# A complicated operation on a pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I would like to obtain, for each id_1, the number of common id_2s between the months of December and January. The example below:

| id_1 | id_2 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | 20221216 |
| 12 | 1 | 20230113 |
| 12 | 1 | 20230116 |
| 12 | 2 | 20221213 |
| 12 | 2 | 20230118 |
| 18 | 7 | 20221207 |
| 18 | 7 | 20220907 |
| 18 | 7 | 20230113 |
| 18 | 5 | 20230118 |

should return :

| id_1 | Nb |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 2 |
| 18 | 1 |

I have looked for a short and optimal way to do this but I haven't found it. I would like to avoid doing several merges. Would you have ideas?

Comment: Why is for `18` in ouput `1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can extract the month with [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`dt.month`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html), then compute a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with a custom function (are both months present for a given combination), then [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) to count:

```
(df.assign(month=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.month)
   .pivot_table(index='id_1', columns='id_2', values='month',
                aggfunc=lambda x: set(x)<={1, 12})
   .sum(axis=1).reset_index(name='Nb')
)
```

Or with a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(df['id_1'], df['id_2'],
            values=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.month,
            aggfunc=lambda x: set(x)<={1, 12}
           ).sum(axis=1).reset_index(name='Nb')
```

Output:

```
   id_1   Nb
0    12  2.0
1    18  1.0
```

Intermediate before the `sum`:

```
id_2     1     2     5      7
id_1                         
12    True  True   NaN    NaN
18     NaN   NaN  True  False
```

Or using a double [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
(df.assign(month=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.month)
   .groupby(['id_1', 'id_2'])['month'].agg(lambda x: set(x)<={1, 12})
   .groupby('id_1').sum().reset_index(name='Nb')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to filter your dataframe before counting values:

```
m = df['Date'].astype(int).between(20221201, 20230131)
counts = df[m].groupby('id_1', as_index=False)['id_2'].nunique()
```

Or using DatetimeIndex:

```
m = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d').between('2022-12-01', '2023-01-31')
counts = df[m].groupby('id_1', as_index=False)['id_2'].nunique()
```

Output:

```
>>> counts
   id_1  id_2
0    12     2
1    18     2
```

Suggested by @mozway:

```
counts = df[m].groupby('id_1', as_index=False).agg(Nb=('id_2', 'nunique'))
```

Comment: If you want to rename `id_2` column, use `counts = counts.rename(columns={'id_2': 'Nb'})`

Comment: As I said in my request the expected result for the id_1 == 18 is supposed to be 1, not 2 because for its 2nd id_2 (5) there is no line in december.